# efficient way to operate on the ndarray

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, lambda, scipy, numpy-ndarray

There exist an numpy ndarry `A` of shape `[100,50, 5]`, and I want to expand A as follows. A will be appended with an one-dimensional array of shape `(50, )`. The resulting `A` will have shape `[100,50,6]`.

The element of this one-dimensional array is based on the array in the original ndarray, i.e., `A[:,:,4]` in terms of a given formula, i.e., `A[:,i,5]=A[:,i,4]*B[i]+5    for i = 0:49`  Here `A[:,:,5]` corresponds to the added one-dimensional array.  `B` is another array working as weight.
Besides using a for loop to write this function, how to fullfill this task in a vectorized/efficient way leveraging `numpy` operation

Comment: `A[:,:,4]` is (100,50).  `B` is (50,).  you should be able to add them +5 to make the new 'column'

Comment: For someone who worries about 'vectorized/efficient way', you seem to have skipped over some basic `numpy` reading.  For example https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html#how-to-create-an-array-from-existing-data and following sections.

Answer (score 0):

Make 2 arrays - with sizes that we can look at:

```
In [371]: A = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4); B = np.array([10,20,30])
```

Due to `broadcasting` we can add a (3,) array to (2,3) array

```
In [372]: A[:,:,-1]+B
Out[372]: 
array([[13, 27, 41],
       [25, 39, 53]])
```

we can then convert that to (2,3,1) array:

```
In [373]: (A[:,:,-1]+B)[:,:,None]
Out[373]: 
array([[[13],
        [27],
        [41]],

       [[25],
        [39],
        [53]]])
In [374]: A
Out[374]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
```

and join them on the last axis:

```
In [375]: np.concatenate((A, Out[373]), axis=-1)
Out[375]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3, 13],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7, 27],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 41]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15, 25],
        [16, 17, 18, 19, 39],
        [20, 21, 22, 23, 53]]])
```

Or we can make a target array of the right size, and copy values to it:

```
In [376]: A1 = np.zeros((2,3,5),int)
In [377]: A1[:,:,:-1]=A
In [379]: A1[:,:,-1]=Out[372]
```